# How do I get the RTM nightly build of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net-identity

I'm running Premium VS2013 RC
I have registered with https://www.myget.org/
I have added `www.myget.org/f/aspnetwebstacknightly` as a repository

I've tried several ways to get these nuget packages, including issuing the following Package Manager Console command:

`update-package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core -IncludePrerelease -source http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/`

This gives me an error `The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.`

When I try to pull or search for the package I get asked for credentials I get this dialog (and the credentials I created when I registered with myget.org don't work).

![Connect to www.myget.org][1]

UPDATE: I have followed the blog  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/09/asp-net-identity-nuget-packages-for-the-nightly-builds-are-available-on-myget.aspx

EDIT:

When I changed from:

```
http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/
```

to:

```
https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/
```

it started working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity nighlty packages are now available on MyGet. Please read the following post for more details
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/09/asp-net-identity-nuget-packages-for-the-nightly-builds-are-available-on-myget.aspx

Comment: Can you please try https in the URL of myget feed?

Comment: EXCELLENT! it was missing the `S` in https (but so was the blog...)

Comment: Had no problems installing the packages using myget feed and then clicking on restore packages prompt in nuget package manager dialog in vs2013. I noticed that instead of creating a mdf file this sample uses localdb. A default mvc 5 web app in vs2013 creates a mdf file in your appdata folder by default after first running your app for the first time (and i think you even have to register a user first?). This sample app does not create a mdf file in your appdata folder. There is a mdf db in the appddata folder however that ive no idea what its for but it confused the hell out of me. :)